# Combine two models with OneToOne relationship into one form - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created two custom user models (AbstractBaseUser and a separate for extra information). Is there a way to combine the two models to create one form that the user can use to update all of their information between the two models?

For example, it would be ideal to have something like this (although I know not possible):

```
class ProfileChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'email', first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'website']
```

Thank you in advance for your help! The models are below:

***MyUser:***

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
```

***UserProfile:***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I would suggest doing the processing separately in the form_valid() method similarly to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968417/django-form-with-fields-from-two-different-models/27990603#27990603

Answer (score 2):

Following solution worked for me. I used formsets to create this solution.
My models were as follows,

#### Models:

```
#Custom user model
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

#Related model(One-to-One relationship with custom user)
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
```

After that I created two ModelForms

#### Forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser,Student
from django import forms

# Form for custom user
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
      model = CustomUser
      fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')

class StudentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['user','first_name','middle_name','last_name']
```

Now the main part, I created a simple inline [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) factory to handle Student model as an inline form.

#### Formset

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import CustomUser,Student
from .forms import StudentCreationForm

# As parameters I provided parent Model(CustomUser),child Model(Student) and the Child 
# ModelForm(StudentCreationForm) 

StudentCreationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(CustomUser, Student,form=StudentCreationForm,extra=1,can_delete = False)
```

In views, I created the SignUpForm and StudentCreationFormSet object respectively. And in the POST request first I validated the CustomUser form and saved it without comitting it(commit=False). I created an object of custom user and passed it as a instance to the StudentCreationFormSet to validate the related form. If everything goes fine my both forms will be saved else the errors will be shown in the template.

#### View

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .formsets import StudentCreationFormSet 

def createAccountView(request):
    student_account_form = SignUpForm()
    student_details_formset = StudentCreationFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        student_account_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if student_account_form.is_valid():
            # Validating Custom User form and creating object of it(not comitting as  formset needed to be verified)
            student_account = student_account_form.save(commit=False)
            # Getting Custom User object as passing it as instance to formset
            student_details_formset = StudentCreationFormSet (request.POST,instance=student_account)

            if student_details_formset.is_valid():
                student_account_form.save()
                student_details_formset.save()
                return redirect('login')    
            else:
                student_details_formset = StudentCreationFormSet (request.POST)

    context = {
        'student_account_form':student_account_form,
        'student_details_form':student_details_formset
    }
    return render(request, 'account/createStudentPage.html',context=context)
```

Also note that I am passing both the form and formset in single post request.

#### Template (createStudentPage.html)

```
<form method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ student_account_form.as_p }}
    {{ student_details_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like :

```
class ProfileChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user__username', 'user__email', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'bio', 'website']
```